# FFmpeg extracts different number of frames when using -filter_complex together with the split filter

Tags: ruby, video, ffmpeg, stdout, thumbnails

I am fiddling with ffmpeg, extracting jpg pictures from videos. I am splitting the input stream into two output stream with -filter_complex, because I process my videos from direct http link (scarce free space on VPS), and I don't want to read through the whole video twice (traffic quota is also scarce). Furthermore I need two series of pitcures, one for applying some filters (fps changing, scale, unsharp, crop, scale) and then selecting from them by naked eye, and the other series being untouched (expect fps changing, and cropping the black borders), using them for furter processing after selecting from the first series. I call my ffmpeg command from Ruby script, so it contains some string interpolation / substitution in the form #{}. My working command line looked like:

```
ffmpeg -y -fflags +genpts -loglevel verbose -i #{url} -filter_complex "[0:v]fps=fps=#{new_fps.round(5).to_s},split=2[in1][in2];[in1]crop=iw-#{crop[0]+crop[2]}:ih-#{crop[1]+crop[3]}:#{crop[0]}:#{crop[1]},scale=#{thumb_width}:-1:flags=lanczos,unsharp,lutyuv=y=gammaval(#{gammaval})[out1];[in2]crop=iw-#{crop[0]+crop[2]}:ih-#{crop[1]+crop[3]}:#{crop[0]}:#{crop[1]}[out2]" -f #{format} -c copy #{options} -map_chapters -1 - -map '[out1]' -f image2 -q 1 %06d.jpg -map '[out2]' -f image2 -q 1 big_%06d.jpg
```

#{options} is set when output is MP4, then its value is "-movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov" so I can send it to standard output without seeking capability and uploading the stream somewhere without making huge temporary video files.
So I get two series of pictures, one of them is filtered, sharpened, the other is in fact untouched. And I also get an output stream of the video on the standard output which is handled by Open3.popen3 library connecting the output stream of the input of two other commands.

Problem arise when I would like to seek in the video to a given point and omitting the streamed video output on the STDOUT. I try to apply combined seeking, fast seek before the given time code and the slow seek to the exact time code, given in floating seconds:

```
ffmpeg -report -y -fflags +genpts -loglevel verbose -ss #{(seek_to-seek_before).to_s} -i #{url} -ss #{seek_before.to_s} -t #{t_duration.to_s} -filter_complex "[0:v]fps=fps=#{pics_per_sec},split=2[in1][in2];[in1]crop=iw-#{crop[0]+crop[2]}:ih-#{crop[1]+crop[3]}:#{crop[0]}:#{crop[1]},scale=#{thumb_width}:-1:flags=lanczos,unsharp,lutyuv=y=gammaval(#{gammaval})[out1];[in2]crop=iw-#{crop[0]+crop[2]}:ih-#{crop[1]+crop[3]}:#{crop[0]}:#{crop[1]}[out2]" -map '[out1]' -f image2 -q 1  %06d.jpg -map '[out2]' -f image2 -q 1  big_%06d.jpg
```

Running this command I get the needed two series of pictures, but they contains different number of images, 233 vs. 484.

Actual values can be read from this interpolated / substituted command line:

```
ffmpeg -report -y -fflags +genpts -loglevel verbose -ss 1619.0443599999999 -i fabf.avi -ss 50.0 -t 46.505879999999934 -filter_complex "[0:v]fps=fps=5,split=2[in1][in2];[in1]crop=iw-0:ih-0:0:0,scale=280:-1:flags=lanczos,unsharp,lutyuv=y=gammaval(0.526316)[out1];[in2]crop=iw-0:ih-0:0:0[out2]" -map '[out1]' -f image2 -q 1  %06d.jpg -map '[out2]' -f image2 -q 1  big_%06d.jpg
```

Detailed log can be found here: http://www.filefactory.com/file/1yih17k2hrmp/ffmpeg-20160610-223820.txt
Before last line it shows 188 duplicated frames.

I also tried passing "-vsync 0" option, but didn't help. When I generate the two series of images in two consecutive steps, with two different command lines, then no problem arises, I get same amount of pictures in both series of course. So my question would be, how can I use the later command line, generating the two series of images by only one reading / parsing of the remote video file?

Comment: Please edit your question to include your actual Ruby code, not just the ffmpeg commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to replicate the `-ss` `-t` options for the 2nd output as well i.e.

```
...-f image2 -q 1 %06d.jpg -map '[out2]' -ss 50 -t 46.5 -f image2 -q 1 big_%06d.jpg
```

Each output option (those not before `-i`) only apply to the output that immediately follows.